# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.fn') - Wordpress & shuffle.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've spent hours trying to work this out.

I'm trying to include [shuffle.js](http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) in my Wordpress theme. It's dependant on jQuery 1.9+ & Modernizr.

I've added my scripts via `wp_enqueue_script` (see below)

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'shuffle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.shuffle.js', array( 'modernizer' ), '1', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-shuffle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-shuffle.js', array( 'shuffle' ), '1', true );
```

I've made them dependant on each other and I'm loading them in at the footer.

I've wrapped the 3 `.js` files in some jQuery noConflict Wrappers (see below)

```
(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
})(jQuery);
```

I'm still getting the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined 
jquery.shuffle.js?ver=1:1212

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'shuffle' 
my-shuffle.js?ver=1.6
```

Everything I read points to something not loading in order, to jQuery not loading but I don't think thats the case. Of course I could be wrong :)

Does anyone have any ideas I can try?

### [UPDATE]

I went and got the minified version of jQuery 1.11.1 and replaced it with the one bundled with Wordpress and it all fired into action!

Only half a day lost :(

### [UPDATE 2]

See Kevin's answer below. No need to change the bundled jQuery, there is an updated version of shuffle.js

Comment: *"I when and got the minified version of jQuery 1.11.1 and replaced it with the one bundled with Wordpress and it all fired into action!*" **Don't do that! you'll only cause more problems. Use the one bundled with wordpress, it has $.noConflict() used at the end to avoid conflicts.**

Comment: Shuffle.js is poorly written, it's incorrectly assuming that `$` will exist which is not the case in a wordpress environment. shuffle.js needs to be modified to work properly with wordpress.

Comment: Hi Kevin, how would it have to be modified? Or what would you suggest otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Shuffle.js* is incorrectly using `window.$` instead of `window.jQuery`. Fix it by replacing [this line](https://github.com/Vestride/Shuffle/blob/master/dist/jquery.shuffle.js#L12):

```
factory(window.$, window.Modernizr);
```

with this one:

```
factory(window.jQuery, window.Modernizr);
```

it's [near the top](https://github.com/Vestride/Shuffle/blob/master/dist/jquery.shuffle.js#L12).

---

The author has already fixed this issue, you can download the fixed version from here: https://github.com/Vestride/Shuffle/blob/e6cb28bd1eb4a5ff60b5d2925b1e26d857f3ec2a/dist/jquery.shuffle.js

Comment: Thanks for the link Kevin. Works a treat. Oh man, this was driving me so nuts!

Answer (score 0):

We can't help you, beyond telling you that `jQuery` isn't actually being defined, and that you have to debug this in your browser.

Inspect your page's source, find your `<script src="jquery...">` and figure out if that file is

1. actually being included (no 404's on the error console) and
2. being included above the first attempt to use `jQuery` and
3. being included above any jQuery plugin's `<script>` tags

Comment: Hmmmm, this was my worry. 1. no 404s 2. jQuery is loaded in the head  3. the other scripts are loaded in the footer. Thanks anyway...